# Alamofire GET If-None-Match doesn't work for some reason

Tags: ios, alamofire

If I use `HEAD` and header `"If-None-Match":ETag` and ETag didn't changed on server I get 304 response (which is great). If I use same header, but `GET`, I get 200 response. Here is both codes, maybe someone will spot my mistake:

```
let headers = ["If-None-Match":ETag]
Alamofire.request(.HEAD, useURL, headers: headers)
    .response { response in
        print(response!.statusCode) 
}

Alamofire.request(.GET, useURL, headers: headers)
    .response { response in
        print(response?.statusCode)
}
```

EDIT: Funny thing just happend - the first time I ran app today, both gave me 304, second time GET gave 200, HEAD 304.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Nope, I think what I ended doing is making HEAD request and if data has changed I would do GET, which is not very good, but better than nothing...

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

**Xcode 8.1, Swift 3, Alamofire 4.0**

```
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: useURL)
urlRequest.addValue(ETag, forHTTPHeaderField: "If-None-Match")
urlRequest.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringCacheData

Alamofire.request(urlRequest).response { result in // method defaults to .get
  print(result.response?.statusCode) //Optional(304)
}
```

Comment: Alamofire, by default, tries to cache requests. In order to control this and get the 304, you need to tell Alamofire to back off. This is why the cachePolicy setting is so important.